# Update ClearCase view config spec with command line with changed load rules

Tags: command-line, clearcase

I have a base ClearCase snapshot view that being updated automatically overnight based on config spec file using this command

```
cleartool setcs -overwrite -ptime d:\CS.cs
```

The problem is that the config spec load rules are being changed and if I run the command it ask for confirmation to update load rules

```
R:\>cleartool setcs -overwrite -ptime d:\CS.cs
cleartool: Warning: 1 objects were eliminated from the new config spec's load rules:
"\QA\QTP"
Continue, and unload these objects? [no]
```

So is there a way to tell ClearCase using command line to automatically continue with the update without getting confirmation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Batch Script to Automate a DOS Program with Options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926711/6309)", you could write the right answer in a file, and redirect it to your command.

```
 cleartool setcs -overwrite -ptime d:\CS.cs < yes.txt
```

That way, if the command stops for getting an input, it will have it immediately.

You find a similar approach in "[how to userinput without typing to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12162749/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "-force" option